# Problem intalling opendaylight fluorine on ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, sdn, opendaylight

I'm trying to install opendaylight fluorine on ubuntu 18.04 LTS
when i execute the command 
biyiha@biyiha-PC:~/opendaylight$ ./bin/karaf

I get:

Apache Karaf starting up. Press Enter to open the shell now...
Unable to register security provider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider
Error occurred while checking the system module.

How can i fix this please

Comment: Welcome to SO. Generally it's required that you explain the steps you've already tried to overcome the problem, few people will write code for you but everyone will help you solve the problem for yourself. What code have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

What version of Java do you have installed? I ran into the same problem when setting JAVA_HOME to Java 10 but once I set it to Java 8 it worked.

`export JAVA_HOME="<path to Java 8>"`
`./bin/karaf`